# Как реализовать с помощью паттерна Command команды UNDO/REDO на Java

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Пока не придумал красивое решение для реализации на Java команд UNDO/REDO. Для работы со стеком команд хочу использовать паттерн "Команда", т.е. нужно реализовать сам паттерн "Команда" + пара классов команд, и чтобы из класса клиента при вызове той или иной комманды, вызванные команды добавлялись в стек истории, и чтобы можно было с помощью команда UNDO/REDO откатывать выполненные команды.

Ещё конкретнее, проблема состоит в том, что пока не понимаю где лучше реализовать стек выполненных команд, пока вижу 3 варианта, но хотелось бы услышать мнения тех, кто реализовывал UNDO/REDO на Java.

Итак мои варианты:
1. В классе клиента
2. В классе Invoker(Вызывающий класс)
3. В классе Receiver

Comment: Может пока добавить в класс клиента, а затем переместить в другое место, если не понравится? Мне кажется что для начала неважно, куда их поместить, можно хоть в отдельный класс, а лучше сосредоточиться на написании классов команд, например.

Comment: @diraria, допустим есть два класса команд, и при выполнении команды добавляются в стек на клиенте. Дальше как откатить изменения, которые сотворила команда? Если просто удалять из стека объект команды, то этого кажется недостаточно, придется либо заново запускать стек с командами и перезаписывать результат, либо как-то ещё, не знаю пока как.

Comment: многое зависит от типа операции, вы не привели ни логики не псевдокода

Comment: Я вижу два варианта: 1. Если для команд просто реализуется операция отката, то тогда в класс команды добавляете метод `undo` (к уже существующему методу `do`), при отмене команды будете вызывать этот метод. 2. Иначе можно каждые несколько действий делать снимок состояния (в зависимости от размера снимков и среднего времени применения команд это может быть 10, 100 или 1000), снимки тоже куда-нибудь складывать, при отмене команды загружать последний снимок и применять к нему все следующие за ним команды, кроме последней

Comment: Также хочу заметить, что если все команды будут храниться в стеке и при отмене команды вы будете удалять из стека последний элемент, то метод redo не сможет получить команду, которую надо заново применить. Можно сохранять удалённые команды в ещё один стек, либо вместо стека использовать стек, поддерживающий индексацию и хранить индекс текущей команды.

Comment: @DaysLikeThis, код приведу позже, не хочется привязывать решение к типу операции. Команды UNDO/REDO сейчас реализованы во многих программах, я надеялся узнать у сообщества BEST PRACTICS.

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/uk/design-patterns/command